# Broken dependency in Maven repository - Hibernate 3.6.5 and jboss-jacc-api_JDK4

Tags: hibernate, maven, ivy

Hi,

I try to use Ivy to manage my dependencies in a simple java project. I want to use hibernate 3.6. But when I add the dependency in my ivy.xml and try to resolve it, it fails, saying that it can't find jboss-jacc-api_JDK4 version 1.1.0.

In the maven repository, hibernate depends on that artifact, but if I click on it, I have a "The requested resource () is not available". It's not the case with the other artifacts: I can see a page with the given dependency and can navigate to see all the existing versions of the project.

Is there any problem with the Maven repository? How can I do to use Ivy with hibernate 3.6?

Thanks a lot for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

> can't find jboss-jacc-api_JDK4 version 1.1.0

This artifact is available in the JBoss repository under the groupId "org.jboss.javaee".  This is an older groupId which was never sync'ed to Maven central, so the short term solution is to add the JBoss repository to your build configuration.

https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public

Longer term these artifacts should be copied over to Maven central so that they are available to default Maven builds, and other builds using the central Maven repository.

Comment: Really curious: if I try to connect to the [maven repository](http://mvnrepository.com), the link to the jboss-jacc-api_JDK4 artifact is working (it wasn't before), and I can manage the hibernate dependency with Ivy without having to add the jboss repository. Thanks anyway for your answer.